# Veiled Durga reference

Tags: durga

I often encounter the term, or reference to, a "Veiled Durga"

Can anybody explain the circumstances under which we find that Durga is veiled, or any reason or story at all that will explain the "Veiled Durga" reference?

Comment: Please provide context. Without the context, I can say it is probably a call-out to hidden references to Durga.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
The reference to a "Veiled Durga" can occur in a number of contexts in the Hindu influenced cultures of S.E.Asia, I can find no foundation for this terminology in the stories associated with Durga in mainline Hindu belief.
I am looking for any possible foundation for this terminology in mainline Hindu belief, I am not looking for an explanation that is contextual, in that the understanding depends upon the circumstance, rather I am seeking the foundation for the usage.

Comment: This usage is not common in Hinduism. However "rahasya" somewhat equivalent to "veiled" does exist; however we cannot be sure if this is what has been loosely translated as veiled. So without context, it is difficult to answer.

Comment: Yes, understood. "Rahasya" comes into other languages as "secret", so "veiled" is appropriate. I suppose we could say that the "context" is mostly as a piece of plastic art, say a figurine or similar, that is always female, but has no face. It occurs principally in Java, Bali, Sumatra. These are Hindu influenced cultures, but to my mind there is no foundation in fact to identify a female figure with no face as being necessarily Durga, thus the question:- is there any story or situation where Durga is in a form where she wears a veil?

Comment: 1. Not that I know of.  Some cultures in which women cover their heads may depict Durga donning a veil but no, this is not common or conventional. It is not wrong either 2. There is a form of zakti called chinnamasta - she is a goddess with a severed head. However, the goddess holds her severed head in her hand. The figurine that you mention seems like a non-religious one.